# ASMX Web Service, Android

Tags: android, security, service, web, ksoap2

Android App 
ksoap2 
Using HttpsTransportSE(SSL)
Pass username and password in the header.
Authenticate the username and password in the asmx web service.

I don't want anyone to be able to write their own application and use the web service.  However, I don't want the user to have to enter a username and password.  I'm planning to store a user name and password in the code, but I don't know how secure of a method this is on android.  If you have a better suggestion, then I'd appreciate it.

Can anyone tell me any additional things I can do to secure this application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In generally, whatever is able to read in an application without protection against **reverse engineering**. Store a user name and password in your code isn't good idea.

But it depends on a type of app. There are many ways how you can protect your web services.

Here are a couple of them:

- Basic authentification with username + password
- Username Authentication with Symmetric Key
- Authentification based on token
- SAML
- etc.

Some references for you:

- http://metro.java.net/guide/ch12.html#ahicv1
- http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0.pdf

Comment: My app is only going to take basic contact information.  I'd like to prevent the need for the user to have to input a username and password.

Comment: My app is only going to take basic contact information.  I have three goals.  1.  Preventing someone from sniffing the data which I believed is solved by using a https/ssl connection.  2. Preventing an unauthorized programmer from being able to code an application and use the web service.  Which method is the best for accomplishing number 2?  I wanted to just hard code a username and password in the soap header and then have the web service verify the username and password to prevent access.   3.  I don't want the user to have to enter a username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer above mine already stated, there are quite a few options available for you.

You could use [**SoapHeaders**](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/webservices/doc/SoapHeaders.aspx) to achieve security of your web-service.

Or, implement your own `Permimeter Service Router` to make sure only the authenticated users get access to your private network.

Here is an excellent article on [**Web Service Security**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa480545.aspx) by MSDN.

Comment: I am passing a username and password in a soap header.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, precisely, as you would find in the article I gave the link to.